# linux x11 window manager - blocking mouse events

Tags: linux, x11, xlib, window-managers

Let's assume that a few windows are visible - I need to implement mechanism which will block events for a selected windows, for example when user click a button in window_nr1 and window_nr2 nothing happens but when a user click a button in window_nr3 event is processed. Compositing window manager renders textures and a window location which is actual for XServer may be different, but this is some kind of workaround so let's also assume that a window texture is rendered without transformations. In Compiz XGrabPointer is use to capture mouse events:

```
XGrabPointer (privateScreen.dpy, privateScreen.eventManager.getGrabWindow(), true,
              ButtonReleaseMask | ButtonPressMask | PointerMotionMask ,
              GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, privateScreen.rootWindow(), 
              cursor, CurrentTime);
```

where a creation of grab window looks like this:

```
grabWindow = XCreateWindow (dpy, root, -100, -100, 1, 1, 0,
                            CopyFromParent, InputOnly, CopyFromParent,
                            CWOverrideRedirect | CWEventMask,
                            attrib);
```

In that case mouse events are captured (i.e. redirected only to a window manager event loop) for the whole screen and it looks like that XGrabPointer can't be used for a capture mouse events for a particular window.

Do you have some ideas how to implement such mechanism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the mouse pointer and pass on the events to the destination window.

Comment: Do you mean XSendEvent ? I know windows parameters  so I can resend mouse events only to the windows which are not blocked, but I wonder if it doesn't introduce some lag...

Comment: @Irbis: Yes XSendEvent. And yes, if your WM is not running on the same machine as the X11 server a noticable lag may be introduced. However if the WM and X11 server are on the same machine the added latency should be way below 1ms (only a few couple 10µs or so if the WM is efficiently written).